# Import Error : Theano

Tags: python, anaconda, theano

I installed anaconda distribution python 2.7.11 first. And after that installed theano by keeping it in site-packages. I am unable to import theano . If I type "import theano" It's showing "ImportError: No module named theano". How to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install theano

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html

```
Anaconda
```

An easy way to install most of the dependencies is to install Anaconda. There is a free version available to everybody. If you install their MKL Optimizations product (free for academic, ~30$ otherwise) Theano will also be optimized as we will reuse the faster BLAS version automatically.

The Anaconda installation includes in particular Python (and the development headers), NumPy, SciPy, nose, sphinx, pip, and a acceptable BLAS version.

After installing Anaconda, in a terminal execute this command to install the latest Theano release:

```
$ pip install Theano
```

To install the missing Theano optional dependency (pydot):

```
$ conda install pydot-ng
```